# UI is not updated during a listener callback in android

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

My fragment is

```
public class sample extends Fragment implements statusChanger{

void onResume() {
Listener.registerListener(this);
}

void onPause() {
Listener.deRegisterListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged() {
MyTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
}
```

My Interface is

```
public interface StatusChanger {
void onStatusChanged();
}
```

My callback from another java class is

```
public void onstatusChanged() {
listener.onStatusChanged();
}
```

The above is the outline of my code , I could get a call back from the ordinal java class to my fragment , but the textView is not set to visible and i do not get any runtime errors.

Comment: Can you give more context?

Comment: i checked with logs, my code path actually reached the onStatusChanged() inside the fragment, but the text view is not visible

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it might be a thread issue. What if you run the onStatusChanged() code on the UI thread?

```
@Override
public void onStatusChanged() {
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            MyTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In normal cases, following code will work:

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Update UI here.
    }
});
```

**Note: If you have wrap above code with Handler with a delay then it may not work.**